# Jasper Report Server not working

Tags: jasperserver

I have a problem with the installation of Jasper Server v. 6.4.2 on Redhat 7.2
redhat-release-server-7.5-8.el7.x86_64.
My Tomcat is running and my postgresql

```
[root@ jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2]# ./ctlscript.sh restart
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat/temp/catalina.pid
Tomcat stopped.
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat/scripts/ctl.sh : tomcat stopped
waiting for server to shut down.... done
server stopped
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/postgresql/scripts/ctl.sh : postgresql stopped
waiting for server to start.... done
server started
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/postgresql/scripts/ctl.sh : postgresql  started at port 5432
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat/temp/catalina.pid
Tomcat started.
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2/apache-tomcat/scripts/ctl.sh : tomcat started
```

but went I try to connect to http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro I have this Message 
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /jasperserver-pro

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.20

Comment: What java version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

First of all just check the whether your war file (tomcat> webapps> jasperserver-pro) is there or not.
Sometimes it does get corrupt and deleted while you are running a js-install sh script for database setup.

So while setting up jasperserver, before running js-install sh (/buildomatic/) make one directory in at /buildmomatic/install_resources with name "war" and copy your war file from tomcat> webapps>  to this directory. otherwise, jasperverserver will through error (/war/jasperserver not found).